# Show full word in combination with search in string/array in pHP

Tags: php

I have no clue how to find this answer, so I hope someone knows an answer or the right combination of PHP code.

In my system I give my client the option to set up some keywords like for example:
`Road`, `car`, `transport`, `delivery`

I need a `function`, where if someone does a `search`, the `function` looks in this `string/array` (whatever is easier as a `function`) and shows me the `complete/full` word. So... if it searches for  '`sport`', it shows:
Results tags: `tran`**`sport`**

I tried something with `strpos()`, and maybe that's the right angle, but I just can't seem to find the combination where the result shows the complete word, and not just a part of it.

Comment: Use `\bsport\b` to match `sport` as a standalone word.  Read about using regular expressions with _word boundaries_.

Comment: How about showing attempts, samples, required output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the function search you can find `$search` in `$option` array.

You can run this code [here](http://tpcg.io/9mBVFvce)

```
<?php
    function search($option, $search) {
        $result = array();
        foreach ($option as $s) {
            if (stripos($s, $search) !== false) {  //stripos is case insensitive, strpos() is case sensitive
                array_push($result, $s);
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
    $search = "sport";
    $option = array("Road", "car", "transport", "delivery", "passports", "sportive");
    echo var_dump(search($option, $search));
?>
```

Comment: yes, this is exactly what i needed, thank you so much